# Java Connection Get Request Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, get

I'm trying to send GET request to a website as follows:

```
uRL = new URL(URLString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL.openConnection();    
// optional default is GET
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");    
// add request header
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);    
responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

However, I need to handle exceptions. For example, if exception is thrown then I will try to request again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `while` with `try-catch` so if an `exception` occur go to next iteration otherwise `break` the `loop`

```
int attempts=5;
boolean flag=false;
while(attempts-- > 0){
  try{
   uRL = new URL(URLString);
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL.openConnection();    
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");    
   connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);    
   responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
   flag=ture;
    break;
  }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      continue;
    }
}


 if(flag){
     // mean request executed successfully 
     // don't throw exception, unless you want to break the current flow of execution
    }
```

To limit the attempts , simply use a count variable(attempt) and a flag variable to verify the successful execution

Comment: the flag should be true in while loop instead of ture

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to put it into a `for` loop with a **given amount of possible tries** in order to **prevent an infinite loop**, then anytime an exception is thrown you **catch it and log it** then you can try again. If it could not be done after the fixed amount of tries you could throw an exception.

```
boolean success = false;
for (int i = 1; !success && i <= maxTries; i++) {
    try {
        uRL = new URL(URLString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // add request header
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not access to the server due to {}, try {}/{}", 
            new Object[]{e.getMessage(), i, maxTries}
        );
    }
}
if (!success) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not access to the server");
}
```